# Diode with an enabler function

Tags: transistors, mosfet, diodes, jfet

I need to implement a diode, which only operates, when enabled by external signal. Specifications:

- When the enabling signal is off, there is no current irrespective of voltage (positive or negative, up to 40 V).
- Enabled signal is on, after which the diode behaves normally.
- I have searched a lot of alternatives: JFET, Mosfet, Bipolar transistor etc. but with no luck so far, except one having a two-way switch and diode in series (see attached picture). But I feel there must be simpler way.
  [image]
  Perhaps JFET could be used with suitable biasing and somehow allowing negative voltages in drain? Or, perhaps bipolar transistor enables this by some special arrangement?

Comment: what about an SCR ?

Comment: You don't need the diode in that circuit. Two back to back NMOS MOSFETs will do. But you need to get the gate drive voltages correct.

Comment: one diode + one mosfet will work, there's a diode blocking current in the other direction.

Comment: If timing is not a problem, get a relay. Or you could possibly replace the diode with a SCR, but you'll have the issue with its latching characteristic and it seems you do not want to remove the diode.

Comment: Thanks for quick comments. I need speed, to the tune of microseconds, thus SCR and relay will not work. This idea of diode/single Mosfet might be workable, even though gate drive creates tough challenge.

Comment: Do you need to use the specific diode you have?

Comment: No, any fast enough diode will work. In fact, I do not need diode, but I need diode-like function, when enabled and high impedance when disabled.

Comment: Could you be more specific about speed here? It seems like switching time is a big concern here. Are you dealing with logic or analogue?

Comment: Here are the timings: enable signal goes up (t=0), diode is enabled (t=100 ns). Same for the other direction (disabled->enabled)).Diode speed could be similar to, for example, speeds of typical power Mosfet body diodes. This is analogue switched mode power supply project.

Comment: In its off state, I'm guessing you want a very low leakage current, because the fet or mosfet configuration would have quite a significant leakage current.

Comment: The leakage current does not play a major role in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A p-channel MOSFET (source grounded) with a diode in series with the drain will almost perfectly perform your stated function. There is no need of a second MOSFET.

Your enable will be a negative voltage wrt ground (typically about -2 to -10 depending on the MOSFET) for 'on' and approximately 0V for 'off'. Choose the diode and MOSFET for your desired current, speed etc.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes. This is the way to go: one Mosfet plus a diode.

Comment: well, so please accept this answer, then, @Jyrki

Answer (score 0):

Since you basically want to construct a circuit equivalent to a diode and a switch in series, and want it to switch at high frequencies while not caring about leakage that much, you have various options. As Spehro Pefhany said, you can just have a mosfet and a diode in series and you'll be fine. However there are other ways to achieve what you want.

You can also use a transistor:

[image]

Or utilise a optocoupler, thus using a BJT instead of a diode.

[image]

HOWEVER THERE IS ONE HUGE PROBLEM WITH THE OPTOCOUPLER ONE. THE VEBO WOULD BE WAY OVER AND YOUR CIRCUIT COULD BLOW.

All you need to do now is go on [digikey](http://digikey.com) or [element14](http://element14.com) and search up the component that fits your needs as desired by using the filter option for frequency, current, voltage and etc.